# Design for memory allocators scope

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory, memory-management, scope

I have been reading different articles on memory management in preparing for how I want my architecture to work, with my biggest worries on how the allocators will be used, created and handled throughout the code base. One of the issues is that my design always has the allocator(s) at a global scope, since I don't have a typical singleton design to contain the allocators, they have no real place to live. I would like to avoid using globals for this due to all the issues typical had with using globals.

This lead me to the design of having something such as

```
void* operator new(size_t size, uint32_t type)
{
    return gAllocator.Alloc(size, type);
 }
```

This would then lead to having just the new definition in a header file, with the declaration in a .cpp. This .cpp file would then have the `gAllocator`, only in the .cpp file (and can be accessed in place else except for the new call.

If my design would to be like this, would the `gAllocator` still be a global variable, if not, what type of variable would it be considered? What if it was in the scope of just a namespace?

Comment: Why don't you make a typical singleton for the default allocator instance?

Comment: Potatoswatter: Singletons are typically bad design, especially in game development (my interest).

Comment: Technically, it's not really a singleton if you allow others besides the default. Just follow the singleton pattern to make a safely-initialized global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a plain global is just what you want. For review, in C++ a global (or singleton) should be a local `static` variable in an `inline` function.

```
class myAllocator {
public:
    static myAllocator &getDefaultInstance() {
        static myAllocator theInstance( parameters );
        return theInstance;
    }
};
```

This way, the object is initialized the first time it's used. If you use a typical header declaration + `.cpp` definition, the order of initialization with respect to other globals is undefined, with possible unpredictable consequences. (The "static initialization order fiasco.")

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Yes, it is. The implementation is required to add a mutex around the initialization!

Comment: A global object is simpler and more robust than this kind of a singleton.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin check Google for the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.google.com/?q=static+initialization+order+fiasco) (most results point back to Stack Overflow) to see why the more complicated lazy initialization construct is preferred. If you have an example of a namespace-scope object being more robust, please do tell.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: you enforce proper order of initialization of your globals using Schwarz counter, just like std::cout/cin/clog get initialized before everything else. No need to use clumsy `myAllocator::getDefaultInstance()` syntax.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin A Schwarz counter just manually implements what this idiom does implicitly. But you also have to manually add thread safety, and (critically) the class needs to be implemented around the construct, which means the constructor must be empty… delegation of initialization causes problems. If you want to avoid the function call syntax, you can implement an object which implicitly converts to `myAllocator` type by returning the global instance.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: there is only one thread doing C++ dynamic initialization, so there is no need to make initialization thread-safe when using Schwarz counters. _the class needs to be implemented around the construct, which means the constructor must be empty_ - not necessarily, again take a look how `std::cout` gets initialized.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin In the worst case, the initialization of a global spawns a thread which references another global. The typical Schwarz counter doesn't apply to such situations. It's true that you can avoid such a situation and then ignore multithreading, but idioms should capture the most generality. As for `cout`, implementations vary, but the standard says the default constructor "Constructs an object of class [ios_base|basic_ios] leaving its member objects uninitialized."

Comment: _... the initialization of a global spawns a thread which references another global. The typical Schwarz counter doesn't apply to such situations..._ - quite to the contrary. When using Schwarz counters that makes sure that the other global object has already been initialized by the time another global object refers to it.